# how to add frames to timeline dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, frames, timeline

hate to ask but I actually need to dynamically add 240 frames to a pure AS3 project and then a stop frame on the last frame.

Yes we're back in 2009.

Why?

Because the dynamic, class driven PureAS3 application I've build (swf) is being delivered to a different media owner who's inhouse system (I kid you not) checks all Flash for 10 seconds of frames(hence 240) AND checks for a 'stop();'.

Any help greatly received - I'm assuming this is possible but drawing a blank online - mainly lots of people (rightly so) advising again using the timeline.

Rich

Comment: How does it check that?

Comment: The response is simple, you can't add frames dynamically to a MovieClip period, no work arounds, no dirty hack, you just can't.

Comment: @null I've no idea, this is a commercial media delivery system that they've been running for years but I don't have exposure to the workings. I've just been assured that it does.

Comment: @BotMaster thanks, I thought that might be the case but you never know with years of people hacking Flash if it was one of those undocumented or little known features that oft seem pointless until times like now. Just living in hope.

Comment: You say you have a pure AS3 project. How are you building your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new SWF as a wrapper, with those 240 frames on its main timeline, the 241st frame should contain a `stop()` call and an instance of your project's Main class. This SWF should be validated with whatever engine they have, but retain all the functionality of your pure AS-driven project.

Comment: thanks Vesper, we're going to try to work this angle but currently they're asking for a single swf.

Most likely I'll need to rework it with an FLA base with timeline, it's just that that's equally not ideal.

Comment: @Visualife that suggestion would make a single SWF. That is 240  frames + your code's main Class now instanced in frame 241 y'know.. `import myProject;` and later `var proj : myProject = new myProject();` etc etc..

Comment: @VC.One thanks, I'm gonna give that a go now as the wrapper idea was rejected.
Such a shame that the undocumented 'addFrameScript()' only works on existing frames rather than increasing frames to that length.

Comment: @Vesper I've marked you answer as correct as thought it doesn't actually answer the question it's the best solution considering what I was after isn't actually possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I personally think if you're not leveraging the timeline, you're working too hard. Just all the drudgery involved in positioning and sizing things that you can just put on stage feels like a massive waste of time. I think it's a shame Adobe was so focused on Flex during the release of Flash 9 that they never showed people how to keep the timeline and still have a nice class-based architecture. But that's water under the bridge and you have what you have.

Have you tried just extending the timeline and putting a stop() frame script at the end? If there's nothing on the stage anyway, adding more frames of nothing shouldn't cause an issue, nor should stopping at the end of nothing.

Another thing you could try is having a main timeline with a stop() on frame 1. On frame 1 put a MC that has the Class you are currently using as your Document Class assigned as its Class. As long as you haven't done anything weird where Classes are reaching up to root or trying to know about things they shouldn't, that should also work.

Comment: hi @Amy, I view timeline vs single frame apps as a right tool for the job.
This particular app is a PureAS3 porject so hence no timeline to add the script to. There was also no need for one until now and in this instance would actually complicate the build time as it's also data driven etc. The timeline requirement is purely an un-scoped post build last minute request hence why it's a spanner.

Interestingly your final paragraph is what I've just sent over to see if it works. Waiting to see if they notice the currentFrame count isn't moving or some other snag.

thanks, R